# Pausing Windows 10 virtual machine loses keyboard

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox

I've got two similar systems with Windows 10 VMs in Ubuntu hosts (18.04 and 20.04) on VirtualBox.  Both do the same thing: If I pause the VM (host+P), when it comes back on, the keyboard is apparently captured but I can't type - nothing appears in the VM.  Even restarting Windows within the VM doesn't bring it back.  Strangely, it's not quite 100% guaranteed to break - a brief pause for test purposes sometimes comes back up working, but a longer pause never does.

This means the only way to free up resources for the host is to shut down the VM completely, but login times are several minutes on one system (corporate image over which I have little control), and the software I use it for takes a few minutes to start.  I thought I'd seen other standby options before, but can't see them in this combination.

Neither system has any USB filters enabled; both have guest extensions and keyboard auto-capture. Is the pause feature broken for Windows guests under Linux hosts, or is there some way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is actually due to poor implementation of HyperV by virtualbox. Try disabling hyperV by `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off` and rebooting. Hopefully this should resolve the issue for you.

Comment: I ran out of time to fully test it on my home machine this morning, but first signs are good. I'll carry on later because I want to be confident before trying to get the setting changed on my work machine. Thanks

Comment: Honestly i've been having my own nightmares with virtualbox causing apt update to return incorrect checksums, so i finally bit the bullet today and migrated over to HyperV entirely to avoid the conflict between the two. My hand was forced as I also need to use docker, and hence HyperV.